# ¿no se porque me imprime este error mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in?

Tags: php, mysql

no entiendo por que me sale este error, se de donde es pero no se cual es la razón. cuando yo coloco esto en mi consulta php ("ORDER BY id_informacion DESC") me imprime ese error pero este mismo lo probe con otras tablas de mi base de datos y me finciono correctamaente, po favor nesecito ayuda. Gracias¡

```
<?php
                include("conexion/conexion.php");
                $result = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY id_informacion DESC  ' ); 
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
                   echo "<div style='color:black' border='1'> \n"; 
                    do{
                      echo "<div class='separador' style='width:100%; margin-left:0;'></div><h1 class='titleForm'>".$row["titulo_noticia"]."</h1><br><div class='separador'></div><br>
                      <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($row["fotos_noticia"])."'/><br>
                      <h2>".$row["subtitulo_noticia"]."</h2><br>
                      <p style='color:black; font-size:18'>".$row["descripcion_noticia"]."</p><br>
                      <label style='color:#4b4877'>Autor : ".$row["autor_noticia"]."<br>Publicado el ".$row["fecha"]."</label> \n"; 
            ?>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br>

            <?php
                    }while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); 
                     echo "</div> \n";
                } else { 
                    echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
                } 
            ?>
```

Comment: Agrega or die(mysql_error()); a tu código para imprimir el error que te esta arrojando $result = mysqli_query($conexion,'SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY id_informacion DESC') or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Si dices que el error ocurre cuando pones el `ORDER BY id_informacion`, debe ser entonces que la tabla `noticias` no tiene una columna llamada `id_informacion`. Como quiera tu código no es correcto, usas dos veces `mysqli_fetch_array` para leer un mismo resultado.